Positioning UILabel
I'm using the following code to position the UILabel on the screen
   innerView = UIView(frame: view.bounds)
    self.view.addSubview(innerView)
    
    let headingLbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: innerView.frame.width - 40, height: 30))
    headingLbl.font = UIFont(name: "Inter-Bold", size: 20);
    headingLbl.text = "What are your goals?"
    headingLbl.textAlignment = .center
    headingLbl.textColor = .black
    innerView.addSubview(headingLbl)
    

Unfortunately, the UILabel gets rendered at the very top near the battery and wifi. I can't even see it. But I'm wondering if it will render properly on different iPhones. What's the right way to position the label? I don't want to use AutoLayout.
See attached image.


Instead using CGRect(x, y, width, height) use NSLayoutConstraint.
 innerView = UIView(frame: view.bounds)
self.view.addSubview(innerView)

let headingLbl = UILabel()
headingLbl.font = UIFont(name: "Inter-Bold", size: 20);
headingLbl.text = "What are your goals?"
headingLbl.textAlignment = .center
headingLbl.textColor = .black
headingLbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false // Use it to set constraint correctly
innerView.addSubview(headingLbl)


NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
  headingLbl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: innerView.topAnchor, constant: 20),
  headingLbl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: innerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
  headingLbl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: innerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
  headingLbl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30)
)]

Hope it helps
Edit: If that does not work. Get safeArea and use their's constraint
let safeArea = innerView.safeAreaLayoutGuide

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
  headingLbl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.topAnchor, constant: 20),
  headingLbl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
  headingLbl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
  headingLbl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30)
)]


Use safeAreaInsets
var innerView = UIView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let safeAreaInsets = view.safeAreaInsets

    innerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: safeAreaInsets.left,
                                     y: safeAreaInsets.top,
                                     width: view.frame.width - safeAreaInsets.left - safeAreaInsets.right,
                                     height: view.frame.height - safeAreaInsets.top - safeAreaInsets.bottom))
    self.view.addSubview(innerView)
    let headingLbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:  20, y: 20, width: innerView.frame.width - 40, height: 30))
    headingLbl.font = UIFont(name: "Inter-Bold", size: 20);
    headingLbl.text = "What are your goals?"
    headingLbl.textAlignment = .center
    headingLbl.textColor = .black
    innerView.addSubview(headingLbl)
    innerView.backgroundColor = .red
    self.view.addSubview(innerView)

}
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
     super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

     // Adjust the frame after layout to account for any changes in safe area insets
     if let customView = view.subviews.first {
         let safeAreaInsets = view.safeAreaInsets
         customView.frame = CGRect(x: safeAreaInsets.left,
                                   y: safeAreaInsets.top,
                                   width: view.frame.width - safeAreaInsets.left - safeAreaInsets.right,
                                   height: view.frame.height - safeAreaInsets.top - safeAreaInsets.bottom)
     }
 }

